# UILabel move to point without snapping

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uilabel

I have a UILabel which I have added a GestureRecognizer to.  I am able to drag it around the screen fine but what I am wanting to do is when the label is within an area I want it to stop dragging and have it move smoothly to a designated point within that area.

So if it's x value is greater than 150  move it to x of 200 and y of 150

It does work but it's popping to the location instead of being smoothly moved to the location.

Here is my drag method:

```
- (void)labelDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:label];

// move label
label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x + translation.x,
                           label.center.y + translation.y);

[gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:label];

if (label.center.x > 150){

    [label setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        label.center = CGPointMake(200 , 150);
    }];
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm new to working with animation and points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to wait till panGesture state.So condition required.While using pan gesture you removed userInteraction from label.By removing User Interaction it doesn't remove gesture from UILabel that's why this is happening.To work animation on UILabel you have to leave UILabel after dragging.Remove finger from label and it will animate.Use following code.

```
- (void)labelDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:label];

    // move label
    label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x + translation.x,
                               label.center.y + translation.y);
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:label];

    if (label.center.x > 150){
        [label setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
            [animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:label.center]];
            [animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200.0f, 400.0f)]];
            [animation setDuration:2.0f];

            [label.layer setPosition:CGPointMake(200.0f, 400.0f)];
            [label.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to cancel the UIPanGestureRecognizer while it is still being performed, you can do so. Set the enabled property to NO, and enable it back on completion of the animation.

```
if (label.center.x > 150){
    gesture.enabled = NO;
    [label setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        label.center = CGPointMake(200 , 150);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        gesture.enabled = YES;
    }];
}
```

But then once the label is snapped, you will not be able to drag it since the gesture will always be disabled due to the position of the label. It is better to snap the label when the gesture is ended.

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //check the position and snap the label        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there any way to have the label move instead of it just jumping to the location?  Like a magnet if you drag it near the location it will be pulled in to position.

Comment: @TazmanNZL what do you mean by move instead of jumping? The code above will move the label to the position specified.

Comment: Yes it does move to the location but if it's at say 150 X it will jump to 200 X instead of animating the move from 150 to 200.